# Is there a difference between a command line flag and a command line option?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, flag

I am hearing these two terms interchangeably and I am wondering if there is any difference between them, like flags are for one letter options or flags are after a single dash.

Comment: I haven't seen any evidence to support either assertion below re: the "official" distinction between _flag_ & _option_, which suggests that @Anthon's humble response to the same question over on _unix.stackexchange_ might be more accurate, if less definitive: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285575/whats-the-difference-between-a-flag-an-option-and-an-argument.

Answer (score 17):

You'll probably find "arguments", "options", and "switches" are also often used interchangeably in this context as well.

"Flags" specifically, are Boolean arguments, set by the mere inclusion of the command-line argument, with no additional data needed or allowed for the argument.  If you include the argument/option/flag, it counts as "true" and if you exclude it, it counts as "false".

Example Flag-type argument:

`command.exe -DeleteFiles`

Example of non-flag argument:

`command.exe -ServerName my.server.com`

[More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option)

Comment: Simple and effective explanation. You could probably even put that 2nd paragraph into the tag wiki for flag, since it has no description currently and that makes it a bit less ambiguous.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Build Awesome Command-Line Applications in Ruby 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356913) the main distinction is: a `switch` doesn't take arguments, while a `flag` does. Quoting directly from the book (page 15):

[image]

Typically, if a switch is in the long-form (for example `--foo`), which turns “on” some behavior, there is also another switch preceded with `no-` (for example `--no-foo`) that turns “off” the behavior.

Finally, long-form flags take their argument via an equal sign, whereas in the short form of a flag, an equal sign is typically not used. For example, the `curl` command, which makes HTTP requests, provides both short-form and long-form flags to specify an HTTP request method: `-X` and `--request`, respectively. The following example invocations show how to properly pass arguments to those flags:

```
curl -X POST http://www.google.com
curl --request=POST http://www.google.com
```

Comment: out of curiosity: how would one call the "some string" part of the call? In a first shot I would say it's simply an "argument", but if so, how would one call all arguments including the switches/options/flags? Aren't all these things kind of "arguments"? How could they be distinguished by name?

Comment: I think `-X something` is an argument, for example in Gradle is possible define `gradlew build -x test` . Now about `--request=POST` I would say it is an argument, but I am not sure.